# Qt как подключить  файл sqlite к проекту в Android

Tags: android, qt, c++

Привет всем. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где должен храниться файл, чтобы я смог его загрузить через `QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("путь до файла/файл")` в Android системе... Вроде как в assets, только как туда закинуть этот файл и указать путь?